# Problem with image detection code from github

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, camera, servo

i'm not into programming that much, thats why i need help. I'm trying to import some codes from a guy that built his own cap flap with mouse detection. I've got an Raspberry pi 3b a servo and a camera to run it. But as soon as i start the python detect.py command, it starts getting faliures, because of the camera. But the camera ist connected correctly. I've tested it and it works. So now i need YOUR HELP to find a solution for this problem. The codes are on github https://github.com/NoNameTechnology/AI-cat-flap and the problem is shown in my photo. If you have any questions please let me know. I hope that someone out there in the internet is capable to help me.                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Luis[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDND5.jpg)

we've tried to take a video from a camera  connected to raspberry pi 3b and run it on the code to get image recognisation and detect mouses and cats. But it's not working

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)